# How to update CheckBoxes on the client side after making changes on the server side?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a `DropDownList` and a `CheckBox` on my web form. After the `DropDownList` is clicked and this event is posted back to the server. `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged` event is called on the server side. Inside that event handler, I have `CheckBox.Checked = true`, But I couldn't make the page on the client side to reflect this change (`CheckBox.Checked = true`). How do I achieve this? Or am I in the wrong direction to use the `DropDownList`'s event handler to update the `CheckBox` because the page firstly reloads and then `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged` is called?

Page load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {               
        this.DropDownList1.Items.Clear();                
        AddItemsToDropDownList();   
    }
}
```

DropDownList selected index changed event handler:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var selected = this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    CheckBox checkBox = GetCheckBoxToBeSetByText(selected);
    checkBox.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: "Normally", setting the `Checked` property of the CheckBox should be enough. A few things can make matters more complicated, however. Do you initialize the CheckBox state in your `Page_Load` event handler? Do you use UpdatePanels? Is some Javascript code executed when the page loads on the client side? You could post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found the issue. Actually there is nothing wrong with the code in my original post. But to make a smallest sample when I posted, I removed some "extra" code. The below is the "complete" code (OK, fine, I still removed some code). As you can see, I put the CheckBox into a static Dictionary. Each time the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler is called, it's modifying the CheckBox in that static Dictionary, which means it's modifying the CheckBox object created from the last session? (still not clear here) Looks like each time when a postback message is received, a new set of CheckBox objects are created. Bear with me if this is known to everybody here already because I only have two days of experience on this web development thing up to today.

```
private static Dictionary<Environment, CheckBox> EnvironmentsCheckBoxes;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes = new Dictionary<Environment,CheckBox>();
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes.Add(Environment.Dev1, this.Dev1_CheckBox);
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes.Add(Environment.Dev2, this.Dev2_CheckBox);
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes.Add(Environment.QA, this.QA_CheckBox);
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes.Add(Environment.QA2, this.QA2_CheckBox);
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes.Add(Environment.Demo, this.Demo_CheckBox);
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes.Add(Environment.Prod, this.Prod_CheckBox);
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes.Add(Environment.UAT, this.UAT_CheckBox);
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

    if (selected == "Dev1")
    {
        EnvironmentsCheckBoxes[Environment.Dev1].Checked = true;
    }
    else if (selected == "Dev2")
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```